# browserify chokes when requiring openpgp

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, openpgp, openpgp.js

When I run browserify on a file containing `require ('openpgp')`, the error message says it cannot find ./config module.

Test file:

```
var openpgp = require ('openpgp');
```

Error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './config' from '/usr/lib/node_modules/openpgp/dist'
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
    at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Browserify works fine when requiring other modules, just not openpgp.  The version of openpgp is the latest (2.2.2).

Is this a problem with the openpgp build?  Or is this a browserify problem?

Comment: Is anyone else able to at least duplicate the problem?